# Comparing ObjectId's using redis and mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, mongoose

I have run into some issues when comparing ObjectIds using mongoDB and redis.

I store MongoDB documents as JSON strings in redis and use JSON.parse when retrieving from redis, but this converts the ObjectIds to strings and I am having a hard time converting them back.

I am using NodeJS with mongoose, and have tried the following:

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId(string_of_objectid)
```

but I get the error

```
Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters in hex format
```

Comment: What is the string that you are using when you get that error message?

Comment: string is like "47cc67093475061e3d95369d"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to `trim` your `string_of_objectid`.